# An equality: from one sum to 2 sums.

Tags: summation

I have an equality:
$$
\ddot{a}_{30} = \frac{1}{0.75}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \left( 1 - \frac{30+k}{120}\right) \right)=\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k - \frac{1}{90} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \right) 
$$

**How** from $\frac{1}{0.75}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \left( 1 - \frac{30+k}{120}\right) \right)$ we get $\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k - \frac{1}{90} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \right) ?$

Because I do not understand where we lost $\frac{1}{0,75}$ in the first sum.

Comment: probably worth noting that $0.75 \times 120=90$ and that $120-30=90$

Comment: Hint:

The product of $\frac{1}{0.75}$ and $\left( 1 - \frac{30+k}{120}\right) $ is

$\frac{1}{0.75}-\frac{1}{0.75}\cdot \frac{30}{120}-\frac{1}{0.75}\cdot \frac{k}{120}=\frac{1}{0.75}\cdot \frac{120}{120}-\frac{1}{0.75}\cdot \frac{30}{120}-\frac{1}{0.75}\cdot \frac{k}{120}$ 

$=\frac{90}{0.75\cdot 120}-\frac{k}{0.75\cdot 120}=1-\frac{k}{0.75\cdot 120}$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\frac{1}{0.75}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \left( 1 - \frac{30+k}{120}\right) \right)&= \frac{4}{3}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \left( \frac34 - \frac{k}{120}\right) \right)
\\&=\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \left( 1 - \frac{k}{90}\right) \right)
\\&=\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k - \frac{1}{90} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \right) 
\end{align}

The $\frac43$ and the $\frac34$ cancels out.